# How to save image to Isolate Storage

Tags: c#, wpf, image, isolatedstoragefile

I want to download an image from an url and then save it, as image file, in the isolate storage. I already save there some string values, but i don't know how to save an image file. Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? Saving an image is exactly the same as saving any other type of file

Comment: In order to save a string i create a new StreamWriter and then with method WriteLine , i write it to file. With image what i should to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it also through binary writer as ;

```
byte[] imageBytes;
HttpWebRequest imageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
WebResponse imageResponse = imageRequest.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = imageResponse.GetResponseStream();

using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(responseStream ))
{
    imageBytes = br.ReadBytes(500000);
    br.Close();
}
responseStream.Close();
imageResponse.Close();

FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveLocation, FileMode.Create);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
try
{
    bw.Write(imageBytes);
}
finally
{
    fs.Close();
    bw.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save it through web client as:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(ImageFileUrl, localFileName);
```

Comment: Yes, but with this way it saves the file in a path( i must give it ). I want to save this to Isolated Storage...

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article955-using-isolatedstoragefile-to-store-data-in-wpf-application-class-events.aspx):

Instead of the StreamWriter use the [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) to write bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
 string filePath = Path.Combine(path, "filename.jpg");
  using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, isoFile))
  {
      yourFileStream.CopyTo(fStream);

      //OR

      fStream.Write(yourFileStream.GetBytes(), 0, yourFileStream.GetBytes().Length);
  }
```